# Is there a way I can easily convert this into discord.py [rewrite], and will it be worth the trouble?

Tags: python, discord.py

I was wondering if it was possible to convert this code:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('<:TeamEmoji:1234567890> sign'):
        role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name='role name')
        member = message.mentions[0]
        await member.add_roles(role)
        await message.channel.send('Successfully signed to <:TEAM:123456789>')
```

into Discord.py[rewrite] instead of old. I also wanted to know if I convert it into rewrite version will it work more effectively than the non rewrited version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that if it runs more efficient but I think `rewrite` version is better than `repl.it` and this code is already in rewrite version of the discord.py.

Comment: okay, so this is rewrite? I was confused I thought the functions and labels like `ctx.send("")` was rewrite or is that also rewrite? I am confused

Comment: You use `await ctx.send` when you send messages with commands. It's the commands' first parameter. But you can also use `channel.send()` or `member.send()`.

Comment: also before this closes I would start another question but I cant post for another 90 mins, but is anyones repl.it not working? I am getting this strange error message that states: `exit status 1 Repl.it: Package operation failed.`